# Spring Condition not able to read value from property file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to implement Spring Condition `org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition`as follows:

```
public class APIScanningDecisionMaker implements Condition {

   @Override
   public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {

    // Not able to read the property "swagger.scanner.can.run". It is always NULL.
    String canRunFlagInStr = context.getEnvironment().getProperty("swagger.scanner.can.run");
   // Ignore the rest of the code.
   }
}
```

However, as shown in the above code, when I read the property "swagger.scanner.can.run" it is always NULL. In my property file I have set it to "swagger.scanner.can.run=false".

I also tried to use the `@Value("${swagger.scanner.can.run}")` but even that returns NULL. When I put a debug in this method I can see that it is being called.

Just for the sake of completion I am using the `APIScanningDecisionMaker` as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger
@Conditional(APIScanningDecisionMaker.class)
public class CustomSwaggerConfig {
  // Ignore the rest of the code
}
```

Is there any reason why "swagger.scanner.can.run" is being retrieved as NULL?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe spring doesn't know the file ?

This can be fix on annotated your class where the `@Value("${swagger.scanner.can.run}")`is used :

```
@PropertySource(value="classpath:config.properties")
```

Regards,

Comment: Actually, Spring is able to read the same property in another class which is in the same package. However, that class is annotated as @Configuration. But when I tried to add the same annotation for APIScanningDecisionMaker it was still not able to read the property file.

Comment: Are your property files in the classpath ? Are the deploy solution in multiple jars for web app, what is context of your app please ?

Comment: The @PropertySource value can be with a wildcard char * like this :
@PropertySource(value="classpath*:config.properties"). In this case, it will search your file in each ClassLoader you have in your app

Comment: As I said my other class is able to read the same property from the same file. So it is in the classpath. To answer your second question, yes APIScanningDecisionMaker is in another JAR file. This JAR file is in the WAR file that has the applicationContext.xml

Comment: Do you know that if your are multiple jars in WEB-IN/lib directory, each jar is load by a specific classloader.

Comment: Do you know that if your are multiple jars in WEB-IN/lib directory, each jar is load by a specific classloader.
If You want access a file, in a jar, and your file is an another jar, you will get Exceptions.
By declaring in your META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in the ClassPath section.  and use the SystemClassLoader .

Comment: I understand that. But like I said I have another Java class in the same package and hence in the same JAR file which is able to read the same property file. Why should one Class be able to read it and not the other one?

Comment: In this case you can have Config class that read the properties with the value Annotation, so you will read it one time, and make method to get the field values. If all the class are in same package, no worries ! 
This is a work around, but without debug it i thing i cannot help you anymore !

Comment: Another way, if your property file is located in WEB-INF/classes, try to put it in the same jar of your targeted classes! ClassLoader problem are soon really hard to fix for a senior consultant like me too, but in debug you have a luck to fix it !

Answer (score 0):

---

The object of class implementing "Condition" is created via constructor from Spring, so you can not inject values using @Value annotation. You can do something like below in your code:

```
@Override        
public boolean matches(
ConditionContext arg0, 
            AnnotatedTypeMetadata arg1) {       
        String prop = conditionContext.getEnvironment()
                 .getProperty("arg0");   
//further code   
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `@Conditional` to config class then `APIScanningDecisionMaker` should implement `ConfigurationCondition`. And don't forget to add `@PropertySource` to config class.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationCondition;

public class APIScanningDecisionMaker implement ConfigurationCondition {
    @Override
    public ConfigurationPhase getConfigurationPhase() {
        return ConfigurationPhase.REGISTER_BEAN;
    }
}
```

Properties will have been loaded in `ConfigurationPhase.REGISTER_BEAN` phase.

If you use `@Conditional` for methods then you could implement `Condition`.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually load the properties file, if due to any problem its not loading into spring's context at the time it is constructing your Condition.

```
@Override
public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
  try {
      Properties appProps = new Properties();
appProps.load(context.getResourceLoader().getResource("classpath:app.properties").getInputStream());
      String canRunFlagInStr = appProps.getProperty("swagger.scanner.can.run");
      return Boolean.parseBoolean(canRunFlagInStr);
  } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new ApplicationContextException(("Exception while loading context", e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

this works fine for me

```
public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
    try {
        InputStream i = conditionContext.getResourceLoader().getResource("prop.file").getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i));
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println(out.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}
```