# Spring: Read property from file why executing Condition::match

Tags: java, spring

I want to implement a conditional Bean depending on a flag in my application.properties. Example:

```
// application.properties
service=foobar
```

The idea is to make different service implementations configurable, let assume I got a central configuration class for this service in Spring:

```
@Configuration
@Import({ServiceA.class, ServiceB.class, ...})
public class ServiceConfiguration {
    ...
}
```

And possible service implementations would look like

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceA implements Condition {

    @Bean
    @Conditional(ServiceA.class)
    public Service service() {
        Service a = ...
        return a; 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(
            ConditionContext conditionContext, 
            AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        // getProperty will alsways return null for some reason
        return conditionContext
                .getEnvironment()
                 .getProperty("service")
                  .equals("ServiceA");
    }

    // This will be null anyways
    @Value("${service}")
    private String confService;
}
```

Since the class implementing `Condition` (here just the same class `ServiceA`) will be initialized via default constructor `@Value`-injections won't work. How ever, by what I understand `getProperty()`should return the correct value. What am I doing wrong? How can I access application properties at this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found at "dirty workarround", I really don't like that solution, how ever, it solves the problem. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790111) a `@PropertySource` fixes the problem (I haven't tried this before posting here since it wasn't an accpeted answer).

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value="file:config/application.properties")
public class ServiceA implements Condition {

    @Bean
    @Conditional(ServiceA.class)
    public Service service() {
        Service a = ...
        return a; 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(
            ConditionContext conditionContext, 
            AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        // Will work now
        return conditionContext
                .getEnvironment()
                 .getProperty("service")
                  .equals("ServiceA");
    }    

}
```

Although this works I don't like it for several reason:

- With every implementation I have code redundancy (giving a path to a config file)
- It's highly unmaintainable when having multiple configuration files

  - Example: Behavior like *load default.properties <-then load and overwrite with -> customer.properties* won't work anymore (altough this should be solvable using `@PropertySources` which would, on the other hand, increase code redundancy)