# how to get application property from ConditionContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on spring but not spring boot. I have a class marked as `@Component` (but not as `@Configuration` [it's not config class]). I would like to create it based on the `serviceA.create` property in `app.properties`. It the file it looks like this: `serviceA.create=true`. I would think, that in the code it narrows down to:

```
@Override
    public boolean matches(final ConditionContext context, final AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {

        return Boolean.valueOf(context.getEnvironment().getProperty("serviceA.create"));
    }
```

But based on different questions/answers (f.e. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790111/spring-condition-not-able-to-read-value-from-property-file)) on the same topic, it sounds like adding `@PropertySource(value="classpath:config.properties")` is mandatory for this to work (to actually read the property value).

Question is, if I am able to get property from `ConditionContext` without defining `@PropertySource` ? because currently I am getting `null` without that annotation.

---

It should be done in the following way:

```
@Component
@Conditional(ServiceACondition.class)
@PropertySource(value="classpath:app.properties")
public class ServiceA {
(...)
}
```

and the cond. class

```
public class ServiceACondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(final ConditionContext context, final AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {

        return Boolean.valueOf(context.getEnvironment().getProperty("serviceA.start"));
    }
}
```

Comment: No. the environment delegates to the different `PropertySource` instances.

Comment: updated my question. Is it correct now ?